# How can I add the Safe Args library to my project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-safe-args

I want to add the Safe Args library to my project using Java. I add these in Android Studio, and it downloads and adds them automatically.

```
  def nav_version = "2.7.5"
  // Java language implementation
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

But when I try to add these to my project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.7.5"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
```

Android Studio doesn't reach the download stage and encounters an error

```
No matching variant of androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.5 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5' but:
```

I've been dealing with this issue for a while. Thank you in advance.

I handed the project to someone else for testing, and it worked correctly for them. I don't know why I'm encountering this issue.

Comment: did you add the safeArgs plugin in the build file?

`plugins {
  id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}`

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

Comment: @TiagoPereira17 yes i did it